# Keycloak docker service cannot connect to database. Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null : Unable to create connection

Tags: database, docker, keycloak

When I executed the docker run command, it's throwing me an error. Tables are created in the database but throwing errors.

> docker run -p 8080:8080 -e DB_VENDOR=MYSQL -e DB_ADDR=192.168.18.01 -e DB_PORT=3306 -e DB_USER=keycloak -e DB_PASSWORD=keycloak -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin -e JDBC_PARAMS="useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true" -e JAVA_OPTS="-Djboss.as.management.blocking.timeout=10800" -e KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL=DEBUG -v "D:/test":/opt/jboss/test keycloak/keycloak:latest

```
Error
    ERROR [org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) Error has occurred while updating the database: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set META-INF/jpa-changelog-1.2.0.CR1.xml::1.2.0.RC1::bburke@redhat.com:
         Reason: liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException: java.sql.SQLException: IJ031070: Transaction cannot proceed: STATUS_ROLLEDBACK
            at org.liquibase//liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:607)
            at org.liquibase//liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:51)
            at org.liquibase//liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:79)
            at org.liquibase//liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:214)
            at org.liquibase//liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:192)
            at org.liquibase//liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:188)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@12.0.4//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.updateChangeSet(LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.java:183)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@12.0.4//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.update(LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.java:102)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@12.0.4//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.update(LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.java:81)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@12.0.4//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory$2.run(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:341)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@12.0.4//org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.runJobInTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:228)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@12.0.4//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.update(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:334)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@12.0.4//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.migration(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:306)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@12.0.4//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.lambda$lazyInit$0(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:182)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@12.0.4//org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.suspendJtaTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:654)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@12.0.4//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.lazyInit(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:133)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@12.0.4//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.create(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:81)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@12.0.4//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.create(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:59)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@12.0.4//org.keycloak.services.DefaultKeycloakSession.getProvider(DefaultKeycloakSession.java:274)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@12.0.4//org.keycloak.models.jpa.JpaRealmProviderFactory.create(JpaRealmProviderFactory.java:51)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@12.0.4//org.keycloak.models.jpa.JpaRealmProviderFactory.create(JpaRealmProviderFactory.java:33)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@12.0.4//org.keycloak.services.DefaultKeycloakSession.getProvider(DefaultKeycloakSession.java:274)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@12.0.4//org.keycloak.services.DefaultKeycloakSession.realmLocalStorage(DefaultKeycloakSession.java:199)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-infinispan@12.0.4//org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.RealmCacheSession.getRealmDelegate(RealmCacheSession.java:152)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-infinispan@12.0.4//org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.RealmCacheSession.getMigrationModel(RealmCacheSession.java:145)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@12.0.4//org.keycloak.migration.MigrationModelManager.migrate(MigrationModelManager.java:99)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@12.0.4//org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.migrateModel(KeycloakApplication.java:234)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@12.0.4//org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.migrateAndBootstrap(KeycloakApplication.java:175)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@12.0.4//org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication$1.run(KeycloakApplication.java:138)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@12.0.4//org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.runJobInTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:228)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@12.0.4//org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.startup(KeycloakApplication.java:129)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-wildfly-extensions@12.0.4//org.keycloak.provider.wildfly.WildflyPlatform.onStartup(WildflyPlatform.java:29)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@12.0.4//org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.<init>(KeycloakApplication.java:115)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:152)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.createProviderInstance(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:2815)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.createApplication(ResteasyDeployment.java:371)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.startInternal(ResteasyDeployment.java:283)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:93)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:140)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.init(HttpServletDispatcher.java:42)
            at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
            at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
            at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:305)
            at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:145)
            at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:588)
            at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:559)
            at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
            at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
            at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:601)
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:97)
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
            at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
            at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
            at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
            at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
            at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
    Caused by: liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException: java.sql.SQLException: IJ031070: Transaction cannot proceed: STATUS_ROLLEDBACK
            at org.liquibase//liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection.getURL(JdbcConnection.java:79)
            at org.liquibase//liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:66)
            at org.liquibase//liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:113)
            at org.liquibase//liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.execute(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1277)
            at org.liquibase//liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1259)
            at org.liquibase//liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:582)
            ... 68 more
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: IJ031070: Transaction cannot proceed: STATUS_ROLLEDBACK
            at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.23.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.checkTransactionActive(WrapperDataSource.java:272)
            at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.23.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.checkTransactionActive(WrappedConnection.java:2007)
            at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.23.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.checkStatus(WrappedConnection.java:2022)
            at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.23.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.checkTransaction(WrappedConnection.java:1996)
            at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.23.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.getMetaData(WrappedConnection.java:982)
            at org.liquibase//liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection.getURL(JdbcConnection.java:77)
            ... 73 more
     Error during startup: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to update database
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@12.0.4//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.update(LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.java:117)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@12.0.4//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.update(LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.java:81)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@12.0.4//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory$2.run(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:341)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@12.0.4//org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.runJobInTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:228)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@12.0.4//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.update(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:334)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@12.0.4//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.migration(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:306)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@12.0.4//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.lambda$lazyInit$0(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:182)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@12.0.4//org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.suspendJtaTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:654)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@12.0.4//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.lazyInit(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:133)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@12.0.4//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.create(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:81)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@12.0.4//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.create(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:59)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@12.0.4//org.keycloak.services.DefaultKeycloakSession.getProvider(DefaultKeycloakSession.java:274)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@12.0.4//org.keycloak.models.jpa.JpaRealmProviderFactory.create(JpaRealmProviderFactory.java:51)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@12.0.4//org.keycloak.models.jpa.JpaRealmProviderFactory.create(JpaRealmProviderFactory.java:33)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@12.0.4//org.keycloak.services.DefaultKeycloakSession.getProvider(DefaultKeycloakSession.java:274)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@12.0.4//org.keycloak.services.DefaultKeycloakSession.realmLocalStorage(DefaultKeycloakSession.java:199)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-infinispan@12.0.4//org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.RealmCacheSession.getRealmDelegate(RealmCacheSession.java:152)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-infinispan@12.0.4//org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.RealmCacheSession.getMigrationModel(RealmCacheSession.java:145)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@12.0.4//org.keycloak.migration.MigrationModelManager.migrate(MigrationModelManager.java:99)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@12.0.4//org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.migrateModel(KeycloakApplication.java:234)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@12.0.4//org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.migrateAndBootstrap(KeycloakApplication.java:175)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@12.0.4//org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication$1.run(KeycloakApplication.java:138)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@12.0.4//org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.runJobInTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:228)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@12.0.4//org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.startup(KeycloakApplication.java:129)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-wildfly-extensions@12.0.4//org.keycloak.provider.wildfly.WildflyPlatform.onStartup(WildflyPlatform.java:29)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@12.0.4//org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.<init>(KeycloakApplication.java:115)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:152)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.createProviderInstance(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:2815)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.createApplication(ResteasyDeployment.java:371)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.startInternal(ResteasyDeployment.java:283)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:93)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:140)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.init(HttpServletDispatcher.java:42)
            at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
            at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
            at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:305)
            at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:145)
            at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:588)
            at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:559)
            at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
            at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
            at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:601)
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:97)
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
            at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
            at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
            at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
            at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
            at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
    Caused by: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set META-INF/jpa-changelog-1.2.0.CR1.xml::1.2.0.RC1::bburke@redhat.com:
         Reason: liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException: java.sql.SQLException: IJ031070: Transaction cannot proceed: STATUS_ROLLEDBACK
            at org.liquibase//liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:607)
            at org.liquibase//liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:51)
            at org.liquibase//liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:79)
            at org.liquibase//liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:214)
            at org.liquibase//liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:192)
            at org.liquibase//liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:188)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@12.0.4//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.updateChangeSet(LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.java:183)
            at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@12.0.4//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.update(LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.java:102)
            ... 61 more
    Caused by: liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException: java.sql.SQLException: IJ031070: Transaction cannot proceed: STATUS_ROLLEDBACK
            at org.liquibase//liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection.getURL(JdbcConnection.java:79)
            at org.liquibase//liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:66)
            at org.liquibase//liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:113)
            at org.liquibase//liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.execute(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1277)
            at org.liquibase//liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1259)
            at org.liquibase//liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:582)
            ... 68 more
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: IJ031070: Transaction cannot proceed: STATUS_ROLLEDBACK
            at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.23.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.checkTransactionActive(WrapperDataSource.java:272)
            at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.23.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.checkTransactionActive(WrappedConnection.java:2007)
            at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.23.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.checkStatus(WrappedConnection.java:2022)
            at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.23.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.checkTransaction(WrappedConnection.java:1996)
            at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.23.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.getMetaData(WrappedConnection.java:982)
            at org.liquibase//liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection.getURL(JdbcConnection.java:77)
            ... 73 more
     ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "microprofile-metrics-smallrye")]): java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.metrics-smallrye@21.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.metrics.MicroProfileMetricsSubsystemAdd$2.execute(MicroProfileMetricsSubsystemAdd.java:89)
            at org.jboss.as.controller@13.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:1005)
            at org.jboss.as.controller@13.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:744)
            at org.jboss.as.controller@13.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:468)
            at org.jboss.as.controller@13.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1415)
            at org.jboss.as.controller@13.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.boot(ModelControllerImpl.java:529)
            at org.jboss.as.controller@13.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:515)
            at org.jboss.as.controller@13.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:477)
            at org.jboss.as.server@13.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:451)
            at org.jboss.as.server@13.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:404)
            at org.jboss.as.controller@13.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:416)
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    
    07:37:33,800 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) WFLYSRV0022: Deploy of deployment "keycloak-server.war" was rolled back with no failure message
```

Comment: Try `-e JDBC_PARAMS="useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MySQL server does not send a RSA public key. In this case you need to allow the mysql client to query it from the server with an extra round-trip.

You need to enable [`allowPublicKeyRetrieval`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-connp-props-security.html#cj-conn-prop_allowPublicKeyRetrieval).
Set your `JDBC_PARAMS` to `useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true` for this to work.

Note: Please don't do this in production and enable SSL instead.